# Multiple Count and Group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a db with 2 different tables 1 is for order details with following structure:

```
--------------
|order_id   |
--------------
|1234       |
--------------
|1235       |
--------------
|1236       |
--------------
|1237       |
--------------
```

Another table is for logging number of times the order is updated

```
---------------------------------------------------
|update_id  |   order_id    |   updated_on      |
---------------------------------------------------
|1          |   1234        |   2015-10-27 17:57:28
---------------------------------------------------
|2          |   1234        |   2015-10-28 17:57:28
---------------------------------------------------
|3          |   1235        |   2015-12-27 17:57:28
---------------------------------------------------
|4          |   1236        |   2015-12-28 17:57:28
---------------------------------------------------
|5          |   1236        |   2015-12-28 17:57:28
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want it to show 2 type of count() for each order id for i.e one for the total number of times an order is updated and second one is number of times order updated in today's date (2015-10-28)

```
----------------------------------------------
|order_id   |   updated |   updated_today   |
----------------------------------------------
|1234       |   2       |   1
----------------------------------------------
|1235       |   1       |   0
----------------------------------------------
|1236       |   2       |   2
----------------------------------------------
|1237       |   0       |   0
----------------------------------------------
```

Help would be highly appreciated in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Group by the order id, and do a simple count, and a sum of times the updated date = today.

```
select o.order_id,
       count(ou.order_id) updated,
       sum(date(updated_date) <=> date(now())) updated_today
from   orders o
left join order_update ou on (o.order_id = ou.order_id)
group by o.order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

You only must change the Tablenames and the Fieldnames

```
SELECT
  o.order_id,
  COUNT(*),
  SUM(IF( CURRENT_DATE() = DATE(l.updated_on),1,0) ) AS updated_today
  FROM order o
  LEFT JOIN loggin l ON l.order_id = o.order_id
  GROUP BY o.order_id;
```

Comment: Learned this the other day, you can sum the result of the boolean. The if is superfluous.

Comment: Although, in this case we need to account for NULLS as well. `IFNULL(SUM...,0)`. And also, count the join table rows, otherwise we'll always get an updated count of >= 1.

Comment: but you can use '<=>' operator to ignore this. SELECT DATE('2015-10-27 10:00:00') <=> CURRENT_DATE(), NULL <=>  CURRENT_DATE();